# I have to split the string based on comma(,) delimiter

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to split the string based on comma (`,`) delimeters in snowflake JavaScript. The string after the first comma (`,`) should be returned.

for example, for

```
Kumar,Nagendra,Busetti
```

the output should be

```
Nagendra,Busetti
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String data = "Kumar,Nagendra,Busetti";
int indexFirstComma=data.indexOf(",");
String result=data.substring(indexFirstComma+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like :

```
String payload = "Kumar,Nagendra,Busetti";
String parsedData[] = payload.split(',');
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");

for (int i = 1; i < parsedData.length; i++) {
    joiner.add(parsedData[i]);
}

String result = joiner.toString(); // "Nagendra,Busetti"
```